# In an IF statement, does condition checking continue after one is found to be true (PHP)

Tags: php, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

For IF statements using OR or similar operators, after one is found to be true, does PHP continue checking the rest or does it stop there?
For example.

```
if(true == true OR a_checking_function())
```

Would both be checked, or would PHP just check one?

Comment: This is called _short-circuiting_.

Comment: No, PHP will only test until the first TRUE match, sometimes also known as `lazy evaluation`

Comment: you could write the code to test it in less time than it took to post this question.

Comment: @StrangeOpossum - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Don't know why this is getting downvoted. Despite how easy it may be to test, I think it's a perfectly legitimate question about whether or not PHP utilizes short-circuiting and can be easily answered without either party testing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as soon as the first `true` is found, it goes straight to the code in the braces. If you used an 'AND' keyword, then it would check the second condition.

You may want to look at operator / logic precedence. For example, what would happen for the following conditions?:

```
if($a = $b AND $c = $d AND $e = $f)...
if($a = $b AND $c = $d OR $e = $f)...
if($a = $b OR $c = $d AND $e = $f)...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Clear and precise answer. Thanks.

Comment: @StrangeOpossum I've added a link to operator / logic precedence that you may be interested in reading about.

Answer (score 0):

This is VERY simple to test:

```
<?php
$count = 0;

function testCond($response=false){
    global $count;
    $count++;
    return $response;
}

if(testCond(true) || testCond(false)){
    echo "At least one was true.<br>";
}

echo "testCond() was called $count time(s).";
```

Output:

```
At least one was true.
testCond() was called 1 time(s).
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/bxOiW2

Call a function for each test and have the function increment a global count variable so you get a count of how many times the function was called.